# Prove that the two straight lines $(x²+y²)(\cos²θ\sin²α+\sin²θ)=(x\tanα–y\sinθ)²$ include an angle $2α$

Tags: solution-verification, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, alternative-proof

This problem is provided in S.L. Loney's book on The Elements of Coordinate Geometry. It goes as follows:

Prove that the two straight lines

$$(x^2+y^2)(\cos^2θ\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\theta)=(x\tan\alpha–y\sin\theta)^2$$

Include an angle $2\alpha$.

The way I attempted at it at first was pretty straightforward. First, to isolate the straight lines separately into two equations; which can be done by factoring. Hence I got:

$$(\cos^2α\sin^2θ + \sin^2θ — \tan^2α)x + \tanα\sinθy ± y\sqrt{(\tan^2α\sin^2θ — \cos^4θ\sin^4α — \cos^2θ\sin^2θ\sin^2α + \tan^2α\cos^2θ\sin^2α)} = 0$$

The $±$ breaking the equation into two distinct ones. The next (straightforward) step would be to find the *m's* of the equations, and from them the angle of each line separately. Subtracting the angles from one another we could find the included angle, which is to be proved to be $2α$. Yet, the next step I did gave me a result so big and ugly that I won't be manifesting it here.

I'm still familiarizing myself with Coordinate Geometry, and am trying to understand *equations representing two or more straight lines* more indepth. Naturally, after the result, I developed the notion that there *must* be another intended method that was to be followed. Most of the problems in the book are also of this kind, hence I request the reader if they could illuminate the proper way of resolving the so-presented problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the equation of a "straight" line?

Comment: @BobDobbs an equation that expresses a relation between the coordinates of a straight line in a coordinate system.

Comment: Is this coeffient $(\cos^2α\sin^2θ + \sin^2θ — \tan^2α)$ correct?

Comment: @BobDobbs that's a result I acquired while calculating, and I believe it to be so — correct

Comment: $y \tan{\theta}=x\sin{\alpha}$ seems to be one of the lines of the pair.

Comment: If we take $\theta=0$, the lines are $y=\pm\tan\alpha x$ so the claim is true.

Comment: Good news WA took the square-root: $\pm\tan\alpha(1-\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\theta)$

Comment: @BobDobbs how is it justified that we can take $0$ for $θ$? I fail to see it; thank you much for your time.

Comment: @Camelot823 It is just a case. The lines are found after taking the square root right?

Comment: @BobDobbs ahh, it appears so! Thank you for resolving my issue! This truly was didactic!

Answer (score 2):

We already discussed the question in the comments. But, I want to share the book, Elements of Coordinate Geometry. [S. L. Loney](https://ia600504.us.archive.org/11/items/elementsofcoordi00lone/elementsofcoordi00lone.pdf) and my solution arranged to book's notations. I had already derived the formula in Art 110.

From Art.108-110, we find that $\tan\phi=\frac{2\sqrt{h^2-ab}}{a+b}$ where $\phi$ is an angle included by the lines.

In the example 11 on page 94, after arranging the expression we get $a=\cos^2\theta\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\theta-\tan^2\alpha$, $h=\tan\alpha\sin\theta$ and $b=\cos^2\theta\sin^2\alpha$. Hence,
$$\begin{array}
.\tan\phi&=\large\frac{2\sqrt{\tan^2α\sin^2θ — \cos^4θ\sin^4α — \cos^2θ\sin^2θ\sin^2α + \tan^2α\cos^2θ\sin^2α}}{2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha-\tan^2\alpha}\\
&=\large\frac{2\tan\alpha(1-\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\theta)}{2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha-\tan^2\alpha}\\
&=\tan2\alpha\\
\end{array}$$

Simplifications were made with the help of WA. I think there must be some clever ways to make these simplifications without the help of computer. There were no computers in 1895.

Comment: Thank you much, again! However, what is WA? Some equation-simplifying application? Could you, perhaps, share it with me?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=&x=5&y=3 I don't know who owns this boddy. It is partly free to use.

Comment: @Camelot823 You can accept this answer. Also check your other questions.

Comment: @callculus42 I don't see what you're referring to, unfortunately?

Comment: @Camelot823 You can accept this answer by clicking on the check mark $(\color{limegreen}{\checkmark })$.

Comment: @callculus42 There is always better and you forget all see next question

Comment: @callculus42 I can't see the genius trick here in the simplifactions. He has right not to accept.

Comment: @BobDobbs The problem is, that the OP haven't accepted any answer at all. This does not motivate a user ro answer one of his/her questions in future. And it indicates, that the OP does not appreciate the time the people spend to answer her/his questions.

Comment: @callculus42 it does not matter I am here in math.SE for problems not OPs.

Comment: @callculus42 hey BTW OP Goku is an interesting figure.